# Java Spring MVC Maven project does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee

I'm trying to start web application using maven, spring mvc but it does not work. I get 404 error. Project complies fine, no errors.

Below some links:
Projects tree. [Projects tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5Ogw.png) 
Web.xml [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/svwwh.png)

Main controller.

```
package root;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

/**
 * Created by Nikita on 08.05.2017.
 */
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String home(){
        return "index";
    }
}
```

And Dispatcher-servlet.xml (Did not include namespaces and schemaLocation) `

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="root"/>

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Server logs shows that server has mapped controller and no warnings appeared. 
All libraries are in.

Server logs.

```
[2017-05-08T18:05:19.988+0300] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005] [javax.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1494255919988] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JVM invocation command line:
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\java.exe
-cp
D:/Programms/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
-XX:NewRatio=2
-XX:MaxPermSize=192m
-Xmx512m
-javaagent:D:/Programms/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
-client
-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/cacerts.jks
-Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
-Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish/modules/autostart/
-Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
-Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish
-Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish/modules/endorsed;D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish/lib/endorsed
-Djava.security.policy=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/server.policy
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
-Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/keystore.jks
-Djava.security.auth.login.config=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/config/login.conf
-Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
-Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
-Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
-Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
-Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
-Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
-DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
-Djava.awt.headless=true
-Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131/lib/ext;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131/jre/lib/ext;D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1/lib/ext
-Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
-Djava.library.path=D:/Programms/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/lib;C:/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath;C:/Windows/Sun/Java/bin;C:/Windows/System32;C:/Windows;D:/Programms/Oracle12c/product/12.2.0/dbhome_1/bin;D:/Programms/oracle11gXE/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/server/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common;C:/Windows/System32/wbem;C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0;C:/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone;D:/Programms/Git/cmd;D:/Programms/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/bin
com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
-upgrade
false
-domaindir
D:/Programms/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/domains/domain1
-read-stdin
true
-asadmin-args
--host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=false,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,D:\Programms\glassfish-4.1.2\glassfish4\glassfish\domains,,,domain1
-domainname
domain1
-instancename
server
-type
DAS
-verbose
false
-asadmin-classpath
D:/Programms/glassfish-4.1.2/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
-debug
false
-asadmin-classname
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:21.840+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921757] [timeMillis: 1494255921840] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Running GlassFish Version: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.2  (build 1)]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:21.841+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921757] [timeMillis: 1494255921841] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Server log file is using Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:21.927+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255921927] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [admin-realm] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:21.942+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255921942] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [file] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm] successfully created.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:21.946+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255921946] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Realm [certificate] of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm] successfully created.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.086+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921757] [timeMillis: 1494255922086] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.226+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100] [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921762] [timeMillis: 1494255922226] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Authorization Service has successfully initialized.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.311+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255922311] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-1, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.351+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255922351] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 18ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:9090]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.368+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255922368] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=http-listener-2, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.372+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255922372] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:9191]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.374+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [WARNING] [] [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.Utils] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255922374] [levelValue: 900] [[
  Instance could not be initialized. Class=interface org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.AddOn, name=admin-listener, realClassName=org.glassfish.grizzly.http2.Http2AddOn]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.379+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=16 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921756] [timeMillis: 1494255922379] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:4848]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.409+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921757] [timeMillis: 1494255922409] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 1ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.409+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1494255922409] [levelValue: 800] [[
  GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1.2  (1) startup time : Felix (1 584ms), startup services(657ms), total(2 241ms)]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.480+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jts.startup_msg] [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921762] [timeMillis: 1494255922480] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JTS5014: Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.604+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=18 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1494255921762] [timeMillis: 1494255922604] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Grizzly Framework 2.3.23 started in: 17ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:7676]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.641+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1494255922641] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@54aca26f as OSGi service registration: org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@58a120b0.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.786+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] [tid: _ThreadID=45 _ThreadName=admin-listener(1)] [timeMillis: 1494255922786] [levelValue: 800] [[
  HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.2.Final]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:22.894+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00005] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=59 _ThreadName=Thread-16] [timeMillis: 1494255922894] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JMXStartupService has started JMXConnector on JMXService URL service:jmx:rmi://NikitaPC:8686/jndi/rmi://NikitaPC:8686/jmxrmi]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:23.915+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255923915] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.453+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01002] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924453] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Java security manager is disabled.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.454+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01010] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924454] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Entering Security Startup Service.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.456+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01143] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924456] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading policy provider com.sun.enterprise.security.provider.PolicyWrapper.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.483+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [NCLS-SECURITY-01011] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924483] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Security Service(s) started successfully.]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.633+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924633] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-1 on host/port 0.0.0.0:9090]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.637+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924637] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener http-listener-2 on host/port 0.0.0.0:9191]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.639+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00198] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924639] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created HTTP listener admin-listener on host/port 0.0.0.0:4848]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.656+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924656] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server server]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.658+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00200] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924658] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Created virtual server __asadmin]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.803+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-CORE-00306] [javax.enterprise.web.core] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924803] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Setting JAAS app name glassfish-web]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:24.804+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00201] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255924804] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Virtual server server loaded default web module ]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.251+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925251] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.310+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925310] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.311+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925311] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.311+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925311] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.312+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925312] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.313+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925313] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.313+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925313] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.315+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925315] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.315+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925315] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.316+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925316] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.316+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925316] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.391+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925391] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.391+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925391] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.392+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925392] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.392+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925392] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.393+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925393] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.394+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925394] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.394+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925394] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.395+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925395] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.395+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925395] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.396+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925396] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.396+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925396] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.397+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925397] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.397+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925397] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.398+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925398] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.398+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925398] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.399+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.tools.deployment.common] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925399] [levelValue: 800] [[
  visiting unvisited references]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:25.795+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255925795] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:26.050+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletContainerInitializer] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255926050] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Registering WebSocket filter for url pattern /*]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:26.095+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [jsf.config.listener.version] [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255926095] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Initializing Mojarra 2.2.14 ( 20161114-2152 unable to get svn info) for context '/tableCustomerWeb_war_exploded']]

[2017-05-08T18:05:26.919+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255926919] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:26.920+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255926920] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.088+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927088] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Mon May 08 18:05:27 EEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.194+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927194] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.347+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927347] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 427 ms]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.501+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927501] [levelValue: 800] [[
  WebModule[null] ServletContext.log():Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher']]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.502+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927502] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.508+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927508] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon May 08 18:05:27 EEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.509+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927509] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:27.945+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255927945] [levelValue: 800] [[
  JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:28.615+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255928615] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String root.HomeController.home()]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:29.076+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255929076] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon May 08 18:05:27 EEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:29.162+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255929162] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'dispatcher-servlet': startup date [Mon May 08 18:05:27 EEST 2017]; parent: Root WebApplicationContext]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:29.319+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255929319] [levelValue: 800] [[
  FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 1817 ms]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:29.321+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [AS-WEB-GLUE-00172] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255929321] [levelValue: 800] [[
  Loading application [tableCustomerWeb_war_exploded] at [/tableCustomerWeb_war_exploded]]]

[2017-05-08T18:05:29.380+0300] [glassfish 4.1] [INFO] [] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=49 _ThreadName=admin-listener(5)] [timeMillis: 1494255929380] [levelValue: 800] [[
  tableCustomerWeb_war_exploded was successfully deployed in 6 255 milliseconds.]]
```

Help me please :c

Comment: Can you post your full server logs with debug logging turned on for org.springframework ?

Comment: @PaulNUK i dont know how to enable debug logging, but I can attach server logs. One sec

Comment: do you have a `/WEB_INF/view/index.jsp` ?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch yes, I do, it's shown in project tree image.

Comment: Try chaging /WEB-INF/ to classpath:/ in web.xml

Comment: @code nope, can't find xml.

Comment: how come you're not able to find web.xml in your project ? It's the file you've attached as an image.

Comment: @code application can't find it, if i replace web-inf to classpath.

Comment: can you show me how did you make the change?

Comment: @code <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

Comment: Try with just classpath: (no forward slash)

Comment: @code same situation

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `*` after `/` in `url-pattern` in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Does not help. 
I've have eve found Intellij Spring MVC Maven sample, downloaded it but it does not work too. 
If You can, check please sample.
http://javastudy.ru/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/SpringMVC_JSPHelloWorld.rar

Comment: What is the name of the war file that you are building? And url that is giving you 404?

Comment: The name of the war - tableCustomerWeb:war exploded
404 - http://localhost:8080/tableCustomerWeb/

Comment: Try this if you are running your server from IDE. Open project `properties` > go to `Deployment Assembly` > Click add and select `Java Build path entries` and click next > select `Maven Dependencies` and click finish. Restart your server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the component scan I guess this could be one of the issue

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="package-name" />